# Unable to compile single C++ file in Netbeans, but able to build full project

Tags: c++, c++11, netbeans-8

I am having issue with single file compilation in Netbeans when I right click and try to compile a file. I had other problems as given in "*[Netbeans: cannot find include file <iostream>, also, unable to resolve identifier std, cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23052003/netbeans-cannot-find-include-file-iostream-also-unable-to-resolve-identifie)*" and fixed all other issues. Build works fine, but only compilation issue.

Compilation Error:

```
cd 'C:\Study Materials\C++\CPP Programs MP Compiled\Projects\collegeProject\collegeProject'
C:\MinGW\MSYS 1.0\bin\make.exe -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/FileHandling.o
Cannot run program "C:\MinGW\MSYS" (in directory "C:\Study Materials\C++\CPP Programs MP Compiled\Projects\collegeProject\collegeProject"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Build Log (only Part):

```
cd 'C:\Study Materials\C++\CPP Programs MP Compiled\Projects\collegeProject\collegeProject'
C:\MinGW\MSYS 1.0\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/C/MinGW/MSYS 1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Study Materials/C++/CPP Programs MP Compiled/Projects/collegeProject/collegeProject'
"/C/MinGW/MSYS 1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/collegeproject.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/Study Materials/C++/CPP Programs MP Compiled/Projects/collegeProject/collegeProject'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/FileHandling.o.d"
g++    -c -g -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/FileHandling.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/FileHandling.o FileHandling.cpp
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/admin.o.d"
.
.
.

mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows
g++     -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/collegeproject build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/FileHandling.o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/admin.o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/login.o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/person.o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/staff.o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/student.o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/subjects.o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/utilities.o 
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Study Materials/C++/CPP Programs MP Compiled/Projects/collegeProject/collegeProject'
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Study Materials/C++/CPP Programs MP Compiled/Projects/collegeProject/collegeProject'

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 8s)
```

Comment: Could be a "space" in the program path issue - "C:\MinGW\MSYS" is only part of the path "C:\MinGW\MSYS 1.0". You have to put the path in quotes.

Comment: How to edit? Editing utilities path is disabled when I go to Path variable section.

Comment: I guess setting environmental variables (System variables) will not fix this problem. I could not figure out where to edit this in Netbeans. I understand the problem now.

Comment: May be it could

Comment: OK, I had to rename MSYS 1.0 to MSYS in C:\MinGW and then change make.exe path accordingly. It worked. Thanks for the help. May be you can answer the question in detail so that I can accept this and mark this as a solution to help others. So this is a bug in Netbeans?

Comment: This is more like a workaround :) Did you install MinGW yourself or Netbeans?

Comment: I already had mingw and it automatically picked up I guess. Do not remember how I did that. But other tools may now have issues after this rename and I have to configure other IDEs in case I use them. Workaround I did was to keep duplicate folder MSYS in addition to MSYS 1.0 (Later I need to remove)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the space in the MinGW path "C:\MinGW\MSYS" is only part of the path "C:\MinGW\MSYS 1.0. **Make sure you there are no spaces in the path** where you install MinGW and MSYS.

> ### [mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started](http://mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started)
>
> #### MinGW Installation Notes
>
> MinGW may have problems with paths containing spaces, and if not,
> usually other programs used with MinGW will experience problems with
> such paths. Thus, we ***strongly recommend*** that you ***do not install MinGW
> in any location with spaces in the path name reference***. You should
> avoid installing into any directory or subdirectory having names like
> "Program Files" or "My Documents", etc.

See also [Netbeans and MinGW-w64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8478317/8918119).

Comment: the whole point of naming the default installation directory "Program Files" was to force proper handling of spaces in all Windows programs. Cross platform things don't bother with this